# Как лучше хранить время до завершения чего-либо и проверять его каждый раз

Tags: алгоритм, sql-server, golang

Есть таблица продуктов, их срок ограничен (есть поле date_end), и у меня такой вопрос какой подход выбрать для того чтобы проверят срок у продуктов: сохранять срок в отдельной таблице, и каждый раз уменьшать его значение или же создать сервис, и проверять каждый раз поле date_end продукта, иссякло ли время или нет? Можете дать совет на счет как лучше все это организовать.

Comment: Просто добавить поле либо даты окончания срока действия (в таблицу экземпляров), либо самого срока (в таблицу типов). И в запросе "на лету" вычислять, живое оно или протухло... PS. Второе более компактно, но менее гибко.

Answer (score 0):

Отдельная горутина самое оптимальное решение. Нагрузки никакой не создаст, как со стороны базы данных так и с основного приложения.